# Logging user actions on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using cognito for user management and apiGateway/lambda for API endpoints. I want to log (preferably on S3) the user actions such as :

```
- userA signed in
- userA GET /api/cars
- userA POST /api/cars
```

Is there a way I can do this automatically with an AWS service (or a combination of them) or I will need to do it manually at the application layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloudwatch logs together with API Gateway.

To do this you can create your own log group or choose an existing log group that could be managed by API Gateway. To specify the access details, you select `$context` variables (expressed in a format of your choosing) and choose a log group as the destination. To preserve the uniqueness of each log, the access log format must include `$context.requestId`.

Remember to add the permissions in your API gateway as for example the `AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs` which all the required Cloudwatch permissions.

For more information of how to do this take a look here: [Setting up CloudWatch logging for a REST API in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html)